# 14.04 VNCserver/VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, hardware, tightvncserver

One of these things is making my HD appear full while running.  Virtual Box is running 6 msdos boxes, and vnc is only there to serve virtualbox.  Over time it persistantly fills the HD to 100% in a roughly 24hr period.  Its not the /tmp directory it remains pretty empty.

HELP!!!

this is normal..15% usage, I've just had to restart so I'll post a full hd soon

```
9.3M    /bin
280K    /home
300M    /lib
16M     /etc
37M     /boot
13M     /sbin
4.0K    /mnt
6.4G    /root
16K     /lost+found
4.0K    /usb
20K     /tmp
4.0K    /opt
2.4G    /usr
928M    /var
4.0K    /srv
10G     /
```

Its full again... du is having a hard time.  I see VirtualBox has filled /root with logs again.

```
9.3M    /bin
496K    /home
304M    /lib
16M     /etc
37M     /boot
13M     /sbin
4.0K    /mnt
65G     /root 
16K     /lost+found
4.0K    /usb
20K     /tmp
4.0K    /opt
2.4G    /usr
1.1G    /var
4.0K    /srv
69G     /
```

I delete all the logs, and they are massive. I get..

```
9.3M    /bin
496K    /home
304M    /lib
16M     /etc
37M     /boot
13M     /sbin
4.0K    /mnt
514M    /root
16K     /lost+found
4.0K    /usb
20K     /tmp
4.0K    /opt
2.4G    /usr
1.1G    /var
4.0K    /srv
4.4G    /
```

but df says 100% usage still.

```
/dev/sda1        71960912   71944524          4 100% /
```

Comment: Which folders are getting filled exactly use this `sudo du -hx --max-depth=1 /` to find out might take a while to run but of course if you know this already add to your post?

Comment: well you see thats the thing, I can't find any full folders..Its like something is convincing the kernel the drive is full.  I've been poking about with ncdu finding nothing.  I'm not familar with those parameters so I'll try your du.

Comment: the only odd thing I can see, is for some reason 42Gb stuck in /mnt, implying something isn't mounting properly and writing the my primary drive, but that is a fairly static amount.  I've not long had to restart so its looking ok at the moment. Will get back to you when its filling up

Comment: Please put it into your post and not in the comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is deleting open files.  They remain open at full size until the owning process is restarted.  lsof -L1 shows the problem.  Restarting the VM's cleared the drivespace.

A better solution appears to be to truncate the file rather than delete it with

```
 :>/offending.log
```

so its not actually deleted.

Thanks for your time all